# Ajax data object unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im having hard time traversing this data set pulled from an ajax call to a weather api. I want to get the values of things such as the temp or id but keep getting errors. Ive tried this weather.weather['id'], weather.weather.id, weather.weather[0]. I know the top weather layer is an object. But the second weather is passing an array? That has an object? how do i pull the information from this? I have some idea of doing this for normal data sets but this is acting weird for me. NOTE THIS IS WITH VUEJS

AJAX CALL:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=6356055&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98', function(weather) {
                this.weather_data = weather;
            }.bind(this));
```

This is wear i push the data to my empty array

```
weather_data: [],
```

then for now im just trying to make sure its working within some pretags like this:

```
{{  weather_data.weather[0].id | json}}
```

and here is what is pulled back from the getjson call.

```
       "weather": {
        "coord": {
            "lon": 2.13,
            "lat": 41.4
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ],
        "base": "cmc stations",
        "main": {
            "temp": 285.622,
            "pressure": 1006.71,
            "humidity": 98,
            "temp_min": 285.622,
            "temp_max": 285.622,
            "sea_level": 1015.25,
            "grnd_level": 1006.71
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.61,
            "deg": 267.501
        },
        "clouds": {
            "all": 0
        },
        "dt": 1457178093,
        "sys": {
            "message": 0.0042,
            "country": "ES",
            "sunrise": 1457158704,
            "sunset": 1457200063
        },
        "id": 6356055,
        "name": "Barcelona",
        "cod": 200
    },
```

trying this `weather_data.weather` yeilds this

```
           [
  {
    "id": 801,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "few clouds",
    "icon": "02d"
  }
]
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mca27kfr/

Comment: data.weather.weather[0].id will provide the result. Show us how you are parsing and accessing the data.

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with this types of problems I'd recommend using console.log(your_variable) and looking in the browser's console (F12 in Chrome) what you really have. Otherwise, data.weather.weather[0].id should work, if your original api response is stored in the variable named "data".

Comment: check the edit. I added some more details. I thought this would work too but the vuejs is acting weird with it

Comment: @RickiMoore,  you define weather_data as array. But from your API you get an object. Possibly what you want to do is this:  this.weather_data = weather.weather. Then later on you'd do this.weather_data[0].id to get the id.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me calendar_component.js:1385Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: doing what you said but only going to weather_data[0] gives me this

Comment: {
  "id": 800,
  "main": "Clear",
  "description": "clear sky",
  "icon": "01d"
}

Comment: after you do this `this.weather_data = weather.weather`, can you show what you have in this.weather_data ? Show output from console.log(this.weather_data)

Comment: @RickiMoore, about weather_data[0]. Yes, that's correct, this is the expected behavior. Then in weather_data[0].id you have "800" as you should

Comment: [
  {
    "id": 800,
    "main": "Clear",
    "description": "clear sky",
    "icon": "01d"
  }
]

Comment: well, the problem you are getting now is different from your initial one. If after reading documentation you can't find the answer, you should probably open another SO question since different bits of info are needed to answer that.